# MSBuild target dependencies based on inputs/outputs alone

Tags: msbuild, dependencies

My interpretation of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx is that the `Inputs` and `Outputs` attributes of a `Target` do not affect dependencies whatsoever. Seriously? Is there no way to tell MSBuild which tasks/targets have certain inputs and outputs, and let it figure out the dependencies and build order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MSBuild is a declarative language, the short answer is no.

However it features a bunch of neat tricks you can apply such as **[batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx)**, and **[dynamic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651786.aspx)**. MSBuild also has great extensibility and through its **[API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145008.aspx)** and vast **[community libraries](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com)** so you can achieve (almost) anything you want.

Comment: The way I read that is "it has a great API, so if you need something... build it yourself". I'd prefer to just use something that already works.

Comment: ...that depends. I gave a general answer to a general question. Elaborate on your goals and you might get the solution you were after.

Comment: That's alright, the answer is pretty clear - I need to look elsewhere for a good build system, like cygwin make.